# Using SQL Functions inside Insert Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have an invoice table in my database into which new invoices are inserted. Recently we have upgraded our services and have many users inserting invoices into the table. I have written a function that calculates the next invoice number in the sequence (the sequence isn't just sequential numbering).

```
MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING([InvoiceNumber], 3, LEN([InvoiceNumber]) - 2) AS INT)) FROM [Invoice] WHERE [InvoiceNumber] LIKE @Prefix + '%'
```

I now want to use this function in an insert statement as follows

```
INSERT INTO [Invoice]
([InvoicedTo]
 ,[InvoiceNumber]
 ,[InvoiceDate]
 ,[Description]
 ,[Amount])
VALUES
(@InvoicedTo
 ,NextInvoiceNumber(@Prefix)
 ,@InvoiceDate
 ,@Description
 ,@Amount)
```

What I want to make sure that using this insert statement will guarantee that the invoice number cannot be duplicated when multiple users are generating invoices. If it can result in duplicates, I would appreciate suggestions on how to stop any duplicates occuring.

Many Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont know if this is helpful

```
begin tran
declare @nextInvoiceNumber int = dbo.NextInvoiceNumber(@Prefix)

INSERT INTO [Invoice]
([InvoicedTo]
 ,[InvoiceNumber]
 ,[InvoiceDate]
 ,[Description]
 ,[Amount])
VALUES
(@InvoicedTo
 ,@nextInvoiceNumber
 ,@InvoiceDate
 ,@Description
 ,@Amount)

commit
```

another thing you could/should do is add a constraint to the table that requires it to be unique.
then add error handling in the event this does happen that will just get you another number.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't guarantee uniqueness.

You should wrap the call inside a `serializable transaction`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed the insert script with in a transaction (Begin and Commit/Rollback) with appropriate [isolation level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx).